# syntax error: unexpected end of file reached

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ "$PATH" = "blah" ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Trying to understand how shell sript if/else works but after running it through the interpreter it returns Unexpected end of file

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your script file has been saved with CRLF line terminators, instead of just LF. The shell does not accept CRLF line endings. Change your editor settings so that the file line endings are LF only.

Comment: That shows up as `-bash: ./foo.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` for me...

Comment: @miken32: The posted script has a space at the end of the shebang line.

Comment: try to convert your script from dos text file format (CR-LF) to unix text file format (LF only) by dos2unix utility: `dos2unix yourscript`